# Declaring array using a variable in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am writing a program that needs to take text input, and modify individual characters. I am doing this by using an array of characters, like so:

```
char s[] = "test";
s[0] = '1';
cout << s;

(Returns: "1est")
```

But if I try and use a variable, like so:

```
string msg1 = "test";
char s2[] = msg1;
s2[0] = '1';
cout << s1[0]
```

I get an error: `error: initializer fails to determine size of 's2'`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C-style arrays require literal values for initialization.  Why use C-style arrays at all?  Why not just use std::string...

```
string msg1 = "test";
string s2 = msg1;
s2[0] = '1';
cout << s2[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

The space for all the variables is allocated at compile time. You're asking the compiler to allocate space for an array of chars called `s2`, but not telling it how long to make it.

The way to do it is to declare a pointer to char and dynamically allocate it:

```
char *s2;

s2 = malloc(1+msg1.length()); // don't forget to free!!!!
s2 = msg1; // I forget if the string class can implicitly be converted to char*

s2[0] = '1'

...
free(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think char a[] can't be initialized by a string.
Edit: "a string" is actually a c-type string (char array with '\0' at the end).

Comment: If it cannot be initialized by a string, what should I use instead?

Comment: doesn't std::string have a c_str() method that returns a char* array? (I'm not looking at the docs... just memory here)

Comment: What C Johnson means is that using char a[] = msg1.c_str() can do the trick.

Comment: It returns a const char *. The initializers of the char array have to be characters or something that can be converted to a char

Comment: It *can* be initialized by a string, but it has to be a constant string whose value is known at compile time, and not the result of some expression.

Answer (score -1):

$8.5.1 and $8.5.2 talk about rules related to initialization of aggregates.